# Click on list item based on name using javascript with Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, selenium

I'm working on a web form and I'm trying to click on a given `li` within a `ul` based on the list item's name. So in the below example I would need to click on the option with the text = "Your Employer". I managed to do this with the classic `driver.find_element_by_xpath` but since performance is a big factor on my project, I would need to select all dropdown options with Javascript. I managed to fill out all input fields of the form but I cannot do the same for the dropdown menus.

```
div class="ui-selectmenu-menu ui-front ui-selectmenu-open" id="RegisteredOwner-menu-wrap" style="top: 1898px; left: 130px;" xpath="1">
<ul aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="RegisteredOwner-button" id="RegisteredOwner-menu" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="listbox" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-109" aria-disabled="false" style="width: 281px;">
    <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-108" tabindex="-1" role="option">
        Please select
    </li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item ui-state-focus" id="ui-id-109" tabindex="-1" role="option">The Insured</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-114" tabindex="-1" role="option">Finance/Lease Company</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-115" tabindex="-1" role="option">Your Employer</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-116" tabindex="-1" role="option">None of the Above</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I tried many alternatives but with no success. I managed to open the dropdown but I can't select the specific option. I know this could be done using the option id but I would need to do this with the option name/text as an input.

I believe something similar to this should work:

```
def populate_dropdown(driver, xls):
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='ui-menu-item'][contains(text(),'" + str(xls) + "')]")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need click on **dropdown** field so that all list element gets loaded.
Note: In this case, all list value are dynamic, these value could have the dependency on other field.

Then after use explicit wait to get your required element get loaded. Once the  element is visible , use **click** to select the value .
*Ex: xpath= //li[text()='textInput']*

There is no need of using contains in xpath here, you can directly go with text.

I have also gone through this kind of scenario...I guess this would help

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try using text instead of contains and see if that improves performance. I have already done what you mentioned in your answer and it works just fine. It’s just that I want to improve the performance and be able to fill out the form much quicker and move on to the next row on the input sheet. I’m doing data driven testing.